# Basic question $|x^2| < 9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, absolute-value

I have a rather basic question.

Let's assume that $|x^2| < 9$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then everyone knows that $x \in$ (-3,3). However, I have trouble arriving at the answer based on basic operations.

$$|x^2| < 9$$

$$ -9 < x^2 < 9$$

Since $x^2$ cannot be negative:

$$ 0 \leq x^2 < 9$$

$ 0 \leq x < 3$ when x is positive or zero, OR $-3 < x \leq 0$ when x is negative or zero.

It means $-3 < x < 3$.

Am my reasoning correct?

Comment: Looks OK. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: The right step from $0\leq x^2<9$ is to get to $0\leq |x|<3$ since $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: So, $0 \leq x^2 < 9$. Then, $0 \leq |x| < 3$. Therefore, $-3 < x < 3$ ?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I believe that's what OP did, in effect.

Comment: @5xum yes, "in effect" but I'm just saying how to add a modicum of elegance to the write-up.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Ah, ok. I thought you are saying OP made a mistake.

Comment: @5xum No, there's no mistake.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct, but here is another way of solving it:

(1)  $$|x^2| = x^2$$

(2)  If $$x^2 < A^2$$
(of course, under the assumption that $A > 0$), then
$$x^2 - A = (x + A)(x - A) < 0.$$
It follows that 
$$\left(x + A > 0\right) \land \left(x - A < 0\right),$$
or
$$\left(x + A < 0\right) \land \left(x - A > 0\right).$$
Since $A^2 > x^2 \geq 0$, $x + A < 0$ is false.  Consequently,
$$\left(x > -A\right) \land \left(x < A\right)$$
which can be abbreviated as
$$-A < x < A.$$

Comment: I think OP already "took it", as he solved the problem. He is only asking if his solution is correct.

Comment: Fair enough.  Should I delete my answer, then?

Comment: I don't think it needs deleting. I would just edit it by saying "what you did is correct, but here is another way of solving it:"

Comment: Done.  Thanks @5xum!

Comment: @5xum A trivial point to make; but I always find your moderation of answers/comments to be very fair and to the point.

Comment: @Bacon Umm... thanks. Now you're making me blush :$